# Facing (AttributeError: module 'clickhouse_sqlalchemy.types.common' has no attribute 'Int256')when trying to import great_expectations in deepnote

Tags: python, jupyter, attributeerror, great-expectations, deepnote

did !pip install great expectation in the deepnote, but when i import great_expectations as gx it gives the error. Tried from a different device aswell but getting the same issue. Just wanted to setup a basic great expectation for a demo, if anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

The entire error -----------------------------------------------------------

---

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [3], line 2
1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 import great_expectations as gx
3 df = gx.read_csv("student.csv")

...

AttributeError: module 'clickhouse_sqlalchemy.types.common' has no attribute 'Int256'

tried to import great_expectation python library on deepnote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Megan from Deepnote here. Per the [docs on Great Expectations](https://deepnote.com/docs/great-expectations) here, have you also run `!great_expectations --yes --v3-api init` to initialize GE?